# Collocations for litigation

Tags: collocation, legalese

In the sentence:

> The company's financing prospects worsened after entering litigation
> with several of its business partners.

I found this to be a bit vague, and not placing the emphasis on the right part: the act of litigation itself and the fact that it's not just one, it's multiple. (the who isn't all that important).

From here I tried:

> The company's financing prospects worsened after several ____ of
> litigation came to light.

However, I'm thinking even that reads strangely, perhaps using a measure word like "several instances of litigation" goes against the natural usage.

So to keep things simple, all I need is for the first part of the sentence to be the same and the second part just needs to use several and litigation (not necessarily in that order):

> The company's financing prospects worsened after _______several ______
> litigation.

Comment: Perhaps 'drawn-out' before litigation is enough (unless you really need  to specify that there were separate episodes). But I can't give this as an 'answer' as I'm trying to decide whether the question really involves writing advice.

Comment: *The company's financing prospects* This is badly phrased and ambiguous. -- *worsened after entering litigation* This is badly phrased and ambiguous. -- *with several of its business partners.* it is unclear if you mean *the company **joined with** its business partners*, or *took legal action **against** its business partners*. You need to rewrite the sentence to make your meaning clear - EL&U does not do proofreading.

Comment: A countable term for instances of civil litigation is *lawsuit*. If that s not adequate for your purposes, it needs to be explained why.